# Estimating a paired samples t-test equivalent in mixed model with two random factors

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have data where 880 participants answered 10 questions at time 1 and at time 2. I want to use a mixed model and consider both participants (id) and questions (question) as random effects. I'm using lmer4. My data is in long format with one column for id, one for the question, one for time1 and one for time2.

I thought this model may be appropriate

```
model <- lmer(time1 - time2 ~ 1 + (1|id) + (1|question), data = dlong)
```

However, the df I obtain are quite small df=9.23

Am I using the correct model specification? I essentially just transposed the lm version of a paired samples t-test to lmer with the added random effects, but I'm worried I'm missing something.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your research question ?

Comment: Oh sorry should have specified this. That guesses at time2 will be better, so lower error at time2.

Comment: No worries. So `time1` and `time2` are the individual scores on the 10 questions at each time ? Each of 880 paticipants are measued 20 times - on 10 questions twice, and each of 10 questions are answered twice by 880 participants (ignoring any missing/incomplete data). Have I got all that right ? Can you let us know a bit more about the questions - types of questions, how they are measured/scored, any other relevant info ?

Comment: Yes. Each participant answers the 10 questions at time1 then answers the same 10 questions at time2. The questions are simple estimation questions (e.g., what percent of the world's population lives in China?). The scale was from 0% to 100%.